# i got different result with same code for converting byte to string function running in different JRE version (jre7 and jre8)

Tags: java, encoding

i want upgrade jre7 to jre8 in our product, and i got some error. The root cause is that the title said, the result is not stable.

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;


public class Digest {
    /**
     * 
     * @param args
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     * @throws UnsupportedEncodingException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {

        String userName = "superuser";
        String password = "superuser";

        byte[] userNameBytes = userName.getBytes(Charset.forName("GBK"));
        byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes(Charset.forName("GBK"));

        byte[] hashedBytes = digest(userNameBytes,passwordBytes);

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(hashedBytes));

        String tmp = new String(hashedBytes,Charset.forName("GBK"));
        byte[] newHashedBytes = tmp.getBytes(Charset.forName("GBK"));

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newHashedBytes));
    }

    public static byte[] digest(byte[] username, byte[] password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
    {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        md.reset();
        md.update(password);
        md.update(username);
        return md.digest();
    }
}
```

the sample code is legacy logic. And my question is how to use a workaround to get through this issue.

here are my test cases:

userNmae password encoding result

superuser superuser UTF-8 passed

superuser superuser GBK failed

test62 test62 GBK failed

test62 test62 UTF-8 failed

thanks a lot.

Comment: Why are you converting bytes of a hash into a string? Hash is binary data, not every binary data can be converted into text.

Comment: Here: `new String(hashedBytes,Charset.forName("GBK"))` Instead of using bytes directly, try encoding it, for example into base64

Comment: Blind spot, saw it too late - sorry. @KarolS

Comment: @Shawn What determines "failed" or "passed"? Comparing what to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A conversion from random bytes to String is potentially a lossy operation (depending on the Charset used):

```
String tmp = new String(hashedBytes,Charset.forName("GBK"));
```

Byte values that can't be encoded with the selected CharSet are replaced (usually with a '?'), thus when converting back to byte[] you get a different array of bytes.

In general *never* convert *binary* data to String and back using any CharSet (although it may work for certain charsets, it bears a lot of potential for headaches when you want to transmit the data or store it in a database etc.). There are encodings (e.g. Base64) that are specifically designed to be reversible with the smallest common set of characters (ASCII).

Edit:
This little test program shows that not each character reverses to the same byte in the conversion (look at -128 becoming 63)

```
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CSTest {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        Charset cs = Charset.forName("GBK");
        byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
        for (int i=0; i<bytes.length; ++i)
            bytes[i] = (byte) i;
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
        String s = new String(bytes, cs);
        byte[] b2 = s.getBytes(cs);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, CP437 has a one-byte encoding with exactly 256 characters and they are in common with Unicode. So, conversion between CP437 and Unicode is reversible and preserves all byte values.

Comment: @TomBlodget Thats a good point, I'll try to be a little more verbose on why its still a bad idea.